intl-tel-input with Ruby on Rails and webpack: Cannot find module '../img/flags.webp'
I'm using Ruby on Rails 6 with webpacker. I'm upgrading intl-tel-input from v17 to v23, following the README setup.
/* app/assets/stylesheets/intl-tel-input.scss */

@import '~intl-tel-input/build/css/intlTelInput';

.iti {
  --iti-spacer-horizontal: 20px;
  --iti-path-flags-1x: url('intl-tel-input/build/img/flags.webp');
  --iti-path-flags-2x: url('intl-tel-input/build/img/flags@2x.webp');
  --iti-path-globe-1x: url('intl-tel-input/build/img/globe.webp');
  --iti-path-globe-2x: url('intl-tel-input/build/img/globe@2x.webp');
}

But when I visit the page I see an error:
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../img/flags.webp'

What am I doing wrong?

It looks like my webpack configuration is not handling these relative import paths from within the intl-tel-input source code:
/* node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/css/intlTelInput.css */

:root {
  ...
  --iti-path-flags-1x: url("../img/flags.webp");
  --iti-path-flags-2x: url("../img/flags@2x.webp");
  --iti-path-globe-1x: url("../img/globe.webp");
  --iti-path-globe-2x: url("../img/globe@2x.webp");
  ...
}

Instead of fiddling with Webpack config, my workaround was to move the import to the Rails asset pipeline. Notice I also had to namespace the CSS variables under :root, not .iti, or --iti-spacer-horizontal wouldn't have any effect:
/* app/assets/stylesheets/intl-tel-input.scss */

@import 'intl-tel-input/build/css/intlTelInput';

:root {
  --iti-spacer-horizontal: 20px;
  --iti-path-flags-1x: url('intl-tel-input/build/img/flags.webp');
  --iti-path-flags-2x: url('intl-tel-input/build/img/flags@2x.webp');
  --iti-path-globe-1x: url('intl-tel-input/build/img/globe.webp');
  --iti-path-globe-2x: url('intl-tel-input/build/img/globe@2x.webp');
}

And include that new stylesheet in my layout file:
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'intl-tel-input', 'data-turbo-track': 'reload' %>

Keeping intl-tel-input styles in a separate file makes browser caching more efficient, since they will rarely change.
